# how to make changes in reactjs project on production? on aws ec2?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-ec2

I have react is build on aws I want to made changes but changes not reflect
I created new build on my local server and replace old build with my new build by using ftp, but changes not reflect.
please help
thanks

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit this question to be specifically about what you're having trouble and spefifically what isn't working. Are you asking how to replace a static Javascript file on a web server? It's unclear what "build on aws ec2" means - Stackoverflow might not be able to help you if you aren't familiar with the setup you're using.

Comment: sorry for that.

Comment: i am talking about reactjs production build

Comment: sorry for typo errors. iam using reactjs

Comment: Please edit your question to add clarifying details, be as specific as possible. It's likely your question will be closed otherwise.